# On clicking the image with url should get mail for notification that the image with url has been clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am new to `PHP` and `AJAX`, I do not get any mail on this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js">
  function trigger() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'images/mail.php',
            data: datastring,
        });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Will you add code of `'images/mail.php'` file?

Comment: `<script>` cannot have both `src` attribute and inline content.

Comment: NO JUST KEPT IN THE IMAGES LOCATION

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js">
<script>
  function trigger() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'images/mail.php',
            data: datastring,
        });
  }
</script>
```